# My listview is not being updated even after calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I don't know why but my list view does not get updated...I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() and I also tried another answer where they asked to do this :

```
 private void editTransaction(int position) {
    h = historyItems.get(position);
    historyItems.remove(position);
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 5 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String description = data.getStringExtra("description");
        if (description == null) description = "no description";

        double amount = Double.parseDouble(data.getStringExtra("amount"));

        h.setDescription(description);
        h.setAmount(amount);
        //h.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //this is where I am updating my arraylist....

        historyItems.add(position,h);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        user.makeEdit(h);

    }
}
```

this is in my custom adapter.

```
public class HistoryCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyItems;
HashMap<String,String> iconMapper;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public HistoryCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyItems, HashMap<String, String> iconMapper) {
    this.context=context;
    this.historyItems=historyItems;
    this.iconMapper=iconMapper;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return historyItems != null ? historyItems.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return historyItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);

        holder.tvCat = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
        holder.tvAmt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
        holder.tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }

    holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
    HistoryItem historyItem;
    historyItem = historyItems.get(position);

    holder.tvCat.setText(historyItem.getCategory());
    holder.tvAmt.setText(historyItem.getAmount()+"");

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss");
    Calendar c    = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(historyItem.getTimestamp());
    Date day      = c.getTime();

    holder.tvDate.setText(df.format(day));

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String mDrawableName = iconMapper.get(historyItem.getCategory());
    int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(resID);

    return convertView;
}

public void refresh(ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyItems)
{
    this.historyItems.clear();
    this.historyItems.addAll(historyItems);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tvCat,tvAmt,tvDate;
    ImageView img;
}

}
```

I dont know why is my listview not being updated immediately...Should i switch to ArrayAdapters?

Comment: Is that class an ArrayAdapter? If so, use `adapter.addAll` instead of your refresh method

Comment: It didnt work...it gave me a clear screen

Comment: public void refresh(ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyItems)
    {
        this.historyItems.clear();
        this.historyItems = historyItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: Nope...it extends BaseAdapter

Comment: Any reason why? You are loading an Arraylist, so I'd recommend using ArrayAdapter

Comment: If you see no data, you need to probably make `getCount` not return 0

Comment: You may need to provide more code to help us understand why its not working for you.

Comment: Ok...Ill edit my answer to add more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear your `this.historyItems` then `this.historyItems.addAll(historyItems)`. Hope it works!

Anyway if you try ViewHolder Pattern, you should reuse it:

```
if (rowView == null) {
   // init view, holder
   rowView.setTag(holder)
} else {
   holder = (Holder) rowView.getTag();
}

// fill data
```

maybe its the reason why your listview didnt reflect immediately.

Comment: public void refresh(ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyItems)
    {
        this.historyItems.clear();
        this.historyItems.addAll(historyItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: does your params historyItems have data?

Comment: just keep in mind that `notifiyDataSetChange()` will work if you hold the reference to your historyItems, not something like assigning data in your refresh function.

Comment: Yes it does...I checked it in logs...Also, when i go back and open the listview again , the changes are reflected...they are just not being reflected immediately

Comment: where do you call the `refresh` function?

Comment: I call it in my main activity which has the listview

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception after trying the reusing viewholder pattern...

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works now!! I will update the working code...I also took help from this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486000/android-arrayadapter-duplicates-listview-items Im sorry i cannot upvote you , my reputation is too loww...

Comment: happy to hear that, put your `getTag()` in `else` case to avoid null.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a new ArrayList to `this.historyItems`, the data can no longer be notified because you've lost the reference to the Arraylist that you specified originally.

If you want that method to work, you need to override `getCount` and `getItem`.

But you also need to

```
this.historyItems.clear();
this.historyItems.addAll(historyItems);
```

Or, if using an ArrayAdapter, you don't need the list of as a member variable

```
clear();
addAll(historyItems);
```

Then, notifyDatasetChanged should work

Comment: I am doing this : this.historyItems.clear();
this.historyItems.addAll(historyItems); Also , getCount and getItem are overridden...

Comment: @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return historyItems != null ? historyItems.size() : 0;
    }

    
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return historyItems.get(position);
    }

Comment: Looks good to me. To stop us from guessing at the problems, then, you have to show a [mcve] in your post

Comment: Is my code snippet fine now @cricket_007 ? please take a look....Thank you

Comment: Can you try not having the adapter as an inner class? I think you might be crossing the references to the Arraylist

Comment: It just appears so...its in a different class...it is not an inner class...I actually have more functions in my main which is why the class end race is not there...

Comment: Personally, I see nothing too wrong with what you have.  You can try adding sample data to the adapter in onCreate, and call refresh. Should work fine. The problem may be onActivityResult is clearing a reference to the list somehow

Comment: I tried using ArrayAdapter instead of baseadapter , and i used addAll(historyItems) and now i have a different issue...the item is being updated but the older array also shows in my listview, that is all the items are duplicated...Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is when i use clear first i get a blank screen...and without clear i get duplicates!!! This is soo frustrating!!!

Comment: If you add data after clearing, and finally end with a notifyDatasetChanged, then I don't understand how that situation could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `.setAdapter(adapter)` before call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this method

```
public void refresh(ArrayList<HistoryItem> historyitems)
{
    this.historyItems=historyitems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Do this. It will work